# Starting YouTrack as a service fails without error message

Tags: linux, ubuntu, youtrack

I've followed the [directions to setup YouTrack as a service](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD6/YouTrack+JAR+as+a+Service+on+Linux) provided by JetBrains, however when I try to use the command:

`service youtrack start`

I get the following message:

```
"/home/youtrack/standalone/bin/wrapper"
"/home/youtrack/standalone/conf/wrapper.conf"
wrapper.syslog.ident=youtrack
wrapper.pidfile="/home/youtrack/standalone/youtrack.pid"
wrapper.daemonize=TRUE
```

Difficult to figure what it's trying to say but it clearly does not start properly. After the message nothing more happens and no youtrack.pid appears in the `standalone` directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Permissions

The owner of the directory `/home/youtrack` was set properly to the user **youtrack**. However all subdirectories, including `standalone` were all owned by **root**.

After using the command `chown -R youtrack:youtrack /home/youtrack`, the problem was solved.

This also caused `/logs/wrapper.log` to not be able to properly log anything without write permissions, hence the lack of errors.

#### Memory

After fixing the file/folder permissions, YouTrack was still failing to start. This was due to the initial memory allowance being set to `256M`. Changing it to `512M` solved it.