# Youtrack 6 reboot fails on Fedora and Java Service Wrapper

Tags: java, linux, fedora, youtrack, java-service-wrapper

I have followed http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD6/Linux.+YouTrack+JAR+as+a+Service on Fedora server. Starting Youtrack 6 as "youtrack" user by

```
/etc/init.d/youtrack start
```

command starts properly. I have added youtrack service wrapper on boot by

```
/sbin/chkconfig --add youtrack
```

command. But after server reboot Youtrack application is not running.

```
journalctl -xn
```

command gives me only this hint

```
systemd[4000]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/rc.d/init.d/youtrack: Exec format error
```

I have fixed my permissions like in this thread ''
[Starting YouTrack as a service fails without error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22849379/starting-youtrack-as-a-service-fails-without-error-message)''

But error still occurs. I have pasted default template from the tutorial '/etc/rc.d/init.d/youtrack' with only one change:

```
#export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
```

/usr/java/latest points to Oracle JDK 8.

Answer (score 2):

```
youtrack_initd.template
```

from youtrack tutorial is missing

```
#!/bin/sh
```

on the top of the file. After adding this line "Exec format error" does not occur anymore.